# Crystal Report: How can I use a list of parameter items as a group?

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence, crystal-reports-2008, business-objects

### Background

I have a Crystal Report.

For multiple items entered into a parameter (which I believe becomes a string array), I would like it to group by those values and then run a number of sub-reports for each group item.

### Goal

For items entered as part of a parameter (which allows multiple items), use those items as a group so that I can see multiple sub-reports for those items (including if no data can be found for a given item).

To clarify, the desired process is:

- User runs the report
- User is prompted to enter one or more item numbers into the ItemNumbers parameter
- The ItemNumbers parameter is used to create groupings
- The groupings run several sub-reports for each group (presumably in the group footer)
- The users see the results (or non-results) for each of the subreports under each item group.

### Roadblocks / attempts so far

- Tried to use the parameter as the grouping. This isn't possible as it does not show up in the list of things I can select for a grouping.
- Tried to use a formula to hold the value of the parameter. This is not possible because formulas cannot result in an array.
- Tried to create a StringArray variable to hold the parameter entries, but since it also must be referenced in a selection formula and formulas can't be arrays, this failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't group on a parameter field.  You will need to use it to filter your recordset, then group on one of its (recordset's) fields.

** edit **

I would create a number of queries that compare the individual transaction tables to the 'main' table (LEFT OUTER JOIN), then UNION these queries. Create a report, using this query as the source of a Command object.

Comment: Hi Craig, that's where I'm running into the issue. We're looking at the history of several transaction-based tables related to inventory, but for inventory items that may no longer exist in the main inventory table. So, for a number entered, we need to check several transaction tables (sub-reports), but if it's not in the main inventory table those won't show up. Should I do a massive full join to all tables and then an "or" statement to see if the value shows up in any of them? That could possibly work but seems gross. Thanks for your response!

Comment: I would create a number of queries that compare the individual transaction tables to the 'main' table (LEFT OUTER JOIN), then UNION these queries.  Create a report and using this query as the source of a Command object.

Comment: Hi Craig, the solution for me was indeed to union the possible tables together into a view, do a distinct select on the item numbers I'd want, and then use that as a table for my array to go against in record selection. Thanks for the help! If you edit your question I'd be happy to mark it as the answer.